# Compute $\mathbf E[B_s^4B_t^2-2B_sB_t^5+B^6_s]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion

> Let $\mathbf B=\{B_t\}_{t\ge0}$ a continuous Brownian motion, what is then $\large\mathbf E[B_s^4B_t^2-2B_sB_t^5+B^6_s]$, for $t\ge s$ ?

How can I factorize the expression in the parenthesis, If the last summand were $B_t^6$ instead of $B_s^6$ the expectation would be equal to $\mathbf E[(B_s^2B_t-B_s^3)^2]$ and $E[B_s^2B_t-B_s^3]=0$, can we derive something from there, maybe a typo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $B_t$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $t$, the moments of $B_t$ can be calculated explicitly. For any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have

$$\mathbb{E}(B_t^{2k+1}) = 0 \tag{1}$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}(B_t^{2k}) = t^k \frac{2^k \Gamma(k+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}},$$

in particular,

$$\mathbb{E}(B_t^2) = t \qquad \mathbb{E}(B_t^4) = 3t^2 \qquad \mathbb{E}(B_t^6) = 15 t^3. \tag{2}$$

---

Back to your exercise: We have

$$\begin{align*} B_s^4 B_t^2 - 2 B_s B_t^5 + B_t^6 &= B_t^2 (B_t^2-B_s^2)^2 = B_t^2 (B_t-B_s)^2 (B_t+B_s)^2 \\ &= ((B_t-B_s)+B_s)^2 (B_t-B_s)^2 (B_t+B_s)^2 \\ &= \left[ (B_t-B_s)^4 + 2 (B_t-B_s)^3 B_s + (B_t-B_s)^2 B_s^2 \right] ((B_t-B_s)+2B_s)^2  \end{align*}$$

Expanding also the square $((B_t-B_s)+2B_s)^2$ in the last line, we get a lot of terms. However, using that the odd moments equal $0$, see $(1)$, and using the independence and stationarity of the increments of Brownian motion, this boils down to

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}( B_s^4 B_t^2 - 2 B_s B_t^5 + B_t^6 ) &= \mathbb{E}(B_{t-s}^6) + 4 \mathbb{E}(B_{t-s}^4) \mathbb{E}(B_s^2) + 8 \mathbb{E}(B_{t-s}^4) \mathbb{E}(B_s^2) \\ &\quad + \mathbb{E}(B_{t-s}^4) \mathbb{E}(B_s^2) + 4 \mathbb{E}(B_{t-s}^2) \mathbb{E}(B_s^4)  \\ &\stackrel{(2)}{=} 15 (t-s)^3 + 39 (t-s)^2 s + 4 (t-s) s^2. \end{align*}$$

Finally, since

$$\mathbb{E}(B_t^6 -B_s^6) \stackrel{(2)}{=} 15 (t^3-s^3),$$

we get

$$ \mathbb{E}( B_s^4 B_t^2 - 2 B_s B_t^5 + B_s^6 )  = 15 (t-s)^3 + 39 (t-s)^2 s + 4 (t-s) s^2 - 15 (t^3-s^3)$$

Answer (score 0):

A general formula can be derived:

$E(B^m_t B^n_s)=E(E(B^m_t|{\mathcal F}_s)B^n_s)$

Using Ito's formula and induction,
$E(B^m_t|{\mathcal F}_s)$ can be written in terms of $B_s$, and by induction again, you get the formula.